# Checking for string in array not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to have an array be searched for a string by using a For loop, going through each spot of the array for its length. If the string is present, it should show that string (in this case, a letter). For some reason, even when that letter is there, the output is not being updated.

For example, say the word is DOG.
The output array would look like '▢ ▢ ▢'.
If I guessed 'D', it should update the output array to be 'D ▢ ▢'. The problem here is, it is not doing that.

This is my code related to this part:

```
function encryptLetters() {

    instructions.style.display = "none";
    
     for (i = 0; i < magicyMagic.length; i++) {
        
        if (magicyMagic.substring(i, i + 1) == " ") {
        
        output[i] = "&nbsp &nbsp";
            
    } else if (magicyMagic.substring(i, i + 1) == ".") {
        
        output[i] = ".";
            
    } else {
        
        output[i] = " ▢"
            
    }

  }


  document.getElementById("mysteryWord").innerHTML = output.join("");

  firstTurn();


}

function player1() {

  console.log("Player 1 is going.");
    nowGoing = 1;
    player1Elements.style.display = "block";
    
    alert(playerName1 + " it is your turn. What do you guess?");
  ask();

}

function ask() {

    console.log("Prompting");
    
    var guess = prompt("What letter would you like to guess?");
    var playerGuess = guess.toUpperCase();
    
    console.log(playerName1 + " guessed " + playerGuess);
    
    checkGuessType(playerGuess);

}

function checkGuessType(playerGuess) {

    console.log("Checking type...");

  if (playerGuess.length > 1) {

    console.log(playerName1 + " guessed a word.");

  } else if (playerGuess == "A" || playerGuess == "E" || playerGuess == "I" || playerGuess == "O" || playerGuess == "U") {

    console.log(playerName1 + " guessed a vowel.");

  } else {

    console.log(playerName1 + " guessed a consonant.");

  }
    
    checkForGuess(playerGuess);

}

function checkForGuess(playerGuess) {

    console.log("Checking if letter is present...");

    for (x = 0; x < magicyMagic.length; x++) {
    
    if (playerGuess == magicyMagic.charAt(x)) {
        
            console.log("Ding ding ding!");
            
      lettersMatched = lettersMatched + 1;
      isCorrect = true;
      output[x] = playerGuess;
      lettersMatched = 0;

    }

  }

  if (isCorrect == false && playerGuess !== "") {
    
        console.log("Player did not guess correctly...");

    document.getElementById("pl1Messages").innerHTML = "There are no " + playerGuess + "'s in the word.";
    lettersMatched = 0;
    document.getElementById("lastMessage").innerHTML = "Player 2 (" + playerName2 + ") will now go.";

  }
    
    hasBeenGuessed.push(playerGuess);
    console.log(hasBeenGuessed[0] + " has been added to the list. Players cannot guess this letter again.");


}
```

In the console, I only see the following:

```
"The first player's name is Test1."
"The second player's name is Test2."
"The player(s) have been informed."
"The word is UGANDA"
"Player 1 is going."
"Prompting"
"Test1 guessed A"
"Checking type..."
"Test1 guessed a vowel."
"Checking if letter is present..."
"Ding ding ding!"
"Ding ding ding!"
"A has been added to the list. Players cannot guess this letter again."
```

Although the console.log() statement related to that part appears in the console, nothing updates for the output array. How would I fix this?

P.S. Any variables not seen in the code snippet are most likely global variables, I'm not sure if that changes anything.

EDIT: Here are all the related variables - all the array values are capitalized, but it still doesn't work.

```
var playerName1;
var playerName2;
var nowGoing = 0;
var magicyMagic;
var isCorrect = false;

// ____ Trees (types of trees - 1)
var array1Trees = ["OAK", "ELM", "PINE", "BIRCH", "SPRUCE", "ASPEN", "MAPLE", "CEDAR", "REDWOOD", "CHERRY"];
// ____ (drinks - 2)
var array2Drinks = ["COKE", "FANTA", "SPRITE", "DR. PEPPER", "CRUSH", "WATER", "PEPSI", "LEMONADE", "MILK", "MOUNTAIN DEW"];
// ____ Man (superheroes - 3)
var array3Heroes = ["SPIDERMAN", "AQUAMAN", "BATMAN", "IRONMAN", "SUPERMAN", "ANTMAN", "HEMAN"];
// ____ (games - 4)
var array4Games = ["POKEMON", "MINECRAFT", "TETRIS", "VALORANT", "CALL OF DUTY", "ROBLOX", "SUPER SMASH BROS", "ANIMAL CROSSING", "TERRARIA", "ANGRY BIRDS"];
// ____ (places - 5)
var array5Places = ["CANADA", "NEW YORK", "TEXAS", "GUATEMALA", "PUERTO RICO", "JAMAICA", "THAILAND", "RUSSIA", "HOFFMAN ESTATES", "UGANDA"];
var output = [];
var lettersMatched = 0;
var hasBeenGuessed = [];
```

Comment: Why all those empty lines in the script?

Comment: @Andreas Sorry about those, I press enter a lot to make space. That way it is easier for me to read while working. I usually take those out after I'm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String comparisons are case sensitive. That means that the letter "e" is different from the letter "E". In your code, you are saying that the letter being guessed is a vowel if it's equal to "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", but you are not checking for "A", "E", "I", "O", "U".

As a consequence, you get "Test 1 guessed a consonant" when the input was "E".

If you want the comparison to be case sensitive, you should add the uppercase letters to your check. If you don't care about case sensitivity, you can apply the function [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to your variable playerGuess before comparing it.

Comment: I thought of that as well, but that doesn't seem to be it. All the original words are in all capitals, and I've also tried adding the toUpperCase/toLowerCase methods, but neither work. Thank you for trying, though!

Comment: Well now that you fixed the case sensitivity it finds the correct letters. Your problem now is that you update your variable output but you never update the DOM. You should add  "document.getElementById("mysteryWord").innerHTML = output.join("");" every time you change the output. Or you can add the element to a variable so that you don't have to find it in the DOM every time.

Comment: That works! Thank you so much! I can't believe I forgot that part.